# Getting to Run Bash Commands using only the standard libraries in Scala

Tags: bash, scala, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a Scala script that holds a bunch of classes that are referenced in a test file. I am only able to import the Scala standard libraries. Is it possible to still run shell code?

Comment: What libraries *can* you use? Is the Scala standard library available? This sounds like it could be an instance of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The scala library is available but I am not sure other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have the standard library. The dead simple way is

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "pwd".!!
res0: String =
"/home/me/blah
"
```

If you want to do anything more complex, have a gander at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.package.